# INSERT INTO and then Multiple Select

Tags: mysql, select, insert

Is this possible?

```
INSERT INTO dfjw_favorite_list (`term_id`,`added_at`,`user_id`) SELECT 
trans.id , '1402309310' , '1' FROM dfjw_terms t,dfjw_language_groups g,
dfjw_terms trans WHERE t.id = '11800' AND g.language_group_id = 
t.language_group_id AND trans.language_group_id= g.id
```

After that I want to select from another table but I want to do this inside 1 INSERT Statement. Like this.. but how can I combine it?

```
SELECT id,'1402309310','1' FROM terms WHERE id = '11800';
```

best regards and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may use `union all`

```
INSERT INTO dfjw_favorite_list (`term_id`,`added_at`,`user_id`) 
SELECT 
trans.id , '1402309310' , '1' 
FROM dfjw_terms t,dfjw_language_groups g,
dfjw_terms trans 
WHERE 
t.id = '11800' 
AND g.language_group_id = t.language_group_id
AND trans.language_group_id= g.id
union all
SELECT id,'1402309310','1' FROM terms WHERE id = '11800';
```